# In my query, How do I search for all books that are related to 'Geography'?

Tags: sql, oracle

Query: Give publication date in LL format with label “LL Formatted” and in RR format with label “RR Formatted” of all books that are related to Geography.

Relation Table:
BOOK(Book_ID, Book_Title, Publication_Date, Subject, Publisher)

This is what I've tried, with little knowledge of LL and RR format:

```
SELECT
  to_date(book.publication_date, 'DD-Mon-RR') AS "RR",
  to_date(book.publication_date, 'DD-Mon-YY') AS "LL"
 FROM book
WHERE book.subject LIKE ('Geography')
```

Comment: Sorry, My bad with the question asking style :|

Comment: This is what I have done, with little knowledge:

Select  TO_Date( Book. Publication_date, ‘DD-Mon-RR) as “RR”, To_Date (Book.Publication_date, ‘DD-Mon- YY) as “LL”, 
from   Book
where Book.Subject Like (‘Geography’)

Comment: Ok. So does this not work or something? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You need to close your quotes around your date format model: `'DD-MON-RR'. Are you getting any errors when you run this? What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm just not very sure about my use(and hence the results) of RR and LL formats, is this the right way how i've done it?

Comment: Also I thought 'related to' does not necessarily mean to contain 'Geography' term in it?

Comment: Yes, i googled about it and found [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/974281)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by `'LL'` format. The `'RR'` format is a workaround for the `Y2K` bug.

Your question has nothing to do with `DATE`.

> In my query, How do I search for all books that are related to 'Geography'?

So you want all rows from `BOOKS` table which belongs to `GEOGRAPHY` value as the `SUBJECT` column.

Simply do this -

```
select * from BOOKS
   where upper(subject) = 'GEOGRAPHY`
```

Comment: i think this is ok, but i see `related to` as a contains, so i think will be better use like too, `upper(subject) like '%GEOGRAPHY%'`, are you agreed?

Comment: I dont understand why 'upper' is being used^, i thought it is only used to capitalize??

Comment: Yes, it's for cases where book name be `Geography` for example.

Comment: Ah, right!
@Aramillo : Do you know about the RR and LL formats?

Comment: @Aramillo, OP needs to confirm whether a wild search is needed or not.